# How do I add a group owner with New-MgGroupOwnerByRef / Microsoft Graph PowerShell module 1.1.0?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

When using [Microsoft Graph PowerShell module for groups](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Groups/1.1.0), how can I add an owner? There are no specific parameters - only `AdditionalProperties` and `BodyParameter` in command `New-MgGroupOwnerByRef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users id - can be obtained with `Get-MgUser` - must be put as URL reference in hash value `@odata.id`:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All", "Group.ReadWrite.All"

$group = New-MgGroup -DisplayName "my-new-group" -MailEnabled:$false -mailNickName "my-new-group" -SecurityEnabled

New-MgGroupOwnerByRef -GroupId $group.Id -AdditionalProperties @{"@odata.id"="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/a0512e69-7815-4685-b916-e9da762a578f"}
```

> this solution is valid as of version 1.1.0 - in a later release this command maybe enhanced and have a specific parameter for adding owners